# MS Bot framework doesn't remember authentication

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, botframework

I'm developing a MS Bot with the v4 framework and I'm trying to set up authentication. The problem is that I can authenticate but if I want to recapture the user authentication token by reprompting the dialog (found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/348bde22daa980bff19eab6ab4bab3b0dd164693/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L81)) then I do get a new loginprompt instead of just retrieving the token.

This is what tried:

- using Azure AD v1 and v2
- searching for documentation (but is always deprecated or the same as found at the link)

My code (if you need something else feel free to ask):

```
// Register the Promt
AddDialog(Prompt(ConnectionName));

// Prompts the user to log in using the OAuth provider specified by the connection name.
// Prompt definition
public static OAuthPrompt Prompt(string connectionName) => new OAuthPrompt(
       LoginPromptName,
       new OAuthPromptSettings
       {
           ConnectionName = connectionName,
           Text = "Please login",
           Title = "Login",
           Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
       });

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var state = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(context.Context);
    return await context.BeginDialogAsync(LoginPromptName, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var loginState = await UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(context.Context);
    // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
    // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)context.Result;
    if (tokenResponse != null)
    {
       * DOES SOMETHING WHEN LOGGED IN*
    }
    else
    {
       * DOES SOMETHING WHEN LOGIN FAILED *
    }


    /* !! 
       HERE IS THE PROBLEM IN STEAD OF CHECKING IF THE USER 
       IS ALREADY LOGGED IN AND JUST RETRIEVING THE TOKEN I
       GET A NEW LOGIN SCREEN.
       !!
    */
    var token2Response = await context.BeginDialogAsync(LoginPromptName, null, cancellationToken)


}
```

So basically I want to retrieve the user token so I can check in different methods and dialogs if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to this bug: [OAuthPrompt requires user credentials when message contains guid or 6-digit number](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1596), which currently has a [Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/pull/1850) to fix.

The workaround for now would be to make sure that the bot gets any kind of other user response before ending the dialog. The sample [does it here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/348bde22daa980bff19eab6ab4bab3b0dd164693/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L60) with:

```cs
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to view your token?") }, cancellationToken);
```

I tested adding this to your code in `* DOES SOMETHING WHEN LOGGED IN*` and it worked:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response sorry to keep you waiting. Just one more question: this means that at this time there is no way to let the user log in without having to enter the magic number?

Comment: The 6-digit code is required by some clients, but not all. In Emulator, you uncheck the "Use a sign-in verification code for OAuth Cards" box in Settings. For Web Chat, you need to [use a token instead of a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)